# How do I display:none specific text with a table?

Tags: css

I need to hide “for 1 year” in the following, using css:

```
<tr class=”order-total recurring-total”>
   <th rowspan=”1″>Recurring total</th>
   <td data-title=”Recurring total”>
      <strong><span class=”woocommerce-Price-amount amount”><span class=”woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol”>$</span>425.00</span></strong> for 1 year
      <div class=”first-payment-date”><small>First renewal: July 4, 2020</small></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

my editor requires me to set it up something like:

```
.recurring-total {
    display: none;
}
```

But that hides everything, which I don't want. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you change the markup at all?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have errors: Change all occurrences of `”` to `"`.

Then just change the visibility of the td to `hidden` and all the texts you want visible inside it to `visible`. That will do.

```css
.recurring-total td[data-title='Recurring total'] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.recurring-total td[data-title='Recurring total'] * {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="order-total recurring-total">
    <th rowspan=”1″>Recurring total</th>
    <td data-title="Recurring total">
      <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>425.00</span></strong> for 1 year
      <div class="first-payment-date"><small>First renewal: July 4, 2020</small></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```